# How substitute variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a trouble with set of equations.
I have:

```
x' = f(t, x, u) - it's a set of equations - dimension n
x1' = ..
x2' = ..
x3' = ..
```

and I have a u - it's a vector (u1, u2, u3..)

How I can substitute this u in my set of equations? 
For example :

```
x1' = sin(t) * u1 + sin(u2)
x2' = u2*x2

u1 = sin(1000t)
u2 = cos(1000t)
```

and i need

```
x1' = sin(t) * sin(1000t) + sin(cos(1000t))
           x2' = cos(1000t) * x2
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that you are using symbolic toolbox:

```
syms t u1 u2 x2;
x1prime = sin(t) * u1 + sin(u2);
x2prime = u2 * x2;
```

Then you can use method A or B. Method A:

```
x1prime = subs(x1prime, [u1 u2], [sin(1000*t) cos(1000*t)])
x2prime = subs(x2prime, u2, cos(1000*t))
```

Method B:

```
u1 = sin(1000*t);
u2 = cos(1000*t);
x1prime = subs(x1prime)
x2prime = subs(x2prime)
```

I tested both methods on Matlab R2011A. use what works best for you.

Comment: It was an example.What's about general case ?

Comment: @user1602627 What do you mean?

Comment: The system maybe doesn't contain sin(1000*t) or cos(1000*t)
it maybe random function u(t). and i need substitute u(t) = (u1(t)..un(t)) in system x'1 = f(t, x, u).

Comment: @user1602627 I am not sure what do you mean. If you don't know the mapping for u1, u2, ..., then what do you expect from MATLAB to do for you? Give us an example in mathematics so we may be able to help.

Comment: It's maybe not sin(100t), it's maybe ln(t^2+1) * tg(t). This data is external for my program